# PHP: Printing strings written in an array within an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to print strings inside the array within the array, so it would look more like this:

bob: ball, bat, car

daniel: bat, bear, car

and less like this:

Bob:
Array
(
    [0] => ball
    [1] => bat
    [2] => car
)

Daniel:
Array
(
    [0] => bat
    [1] => bear
    [2] => car
)

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
$b;

$school=array(
"14"=>array("name"=>"Bob","toy"=>array("ball","bat","car")),
"23"=>array("name"=>"Daniel","toy"=>array("bat","bear","car")),
"31"=>array("name"=>"Tom","toy"=>array("bicycle","ball")),
"44"=>array("name"=>"Tim","toy"=>array("train","puzzle","ball","stick")),
"53"=>array("name"=>"Barbara","toy"=>array("bear", "car"))
);


foreach($school as $b)
{
echo $b["name"];
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($b["toy"]);
echo '</pre>';
}
?>
</head>
</html>
```

I tried many things, but I always get the 'string to array conversion' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make string from array, so that use `implode()` and display it as a string like following.

```
foreach($school as $b)
{
    echo "$b[name] : ".implode(',',$b["toy"]);
}
```

Comment: Wow such a fast response It works perfectly! Thanks a billion!

Comment: it says I have to wait one minute

Comment: I think that does it. Thanks for your time, effort and help!

Answer (score 1):

replace `print_r ($b["toy"]);` with:

```
echo implode(', ', $b["toy"] );
```